# Radio buttons with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, radio-button, react-hook-form

I created a form with react-hook-form. It logs "fullName" and "city" correctly in the console, but not the radio buttons. With the radio buttons you get as result "null".

My code is as follows.

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";

function App() {
    const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();

    function onSubmitButton(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Order weather</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitButton)}>
                <input
                    {...register("fullName")}
                    type="text"
                    name="fullName"
                    placeholder="Name and surname"
                    id="name"
                />
                <input
                    {...register("city")}
                    type="text"
                    name="city"
                    placeholder="City"
                    id="city"
                />
                <p>I would like to:</p>
                <label htmlFor="field-rain">
                    <input
                        {...register("rain")}
                        type="radio"
                        name="weather"
                        value="rain"
                        id="field-rain"
                    />
                    Rain
                </label>
                <label htmlFor="field-wind">
                    <input
                        {...register("wind")}
                        type="radio"
                        name="weather"
                        value="wind"
                        id="field-wind"
                    />
                    Lots of wind
                </label>
                <label htmlFor="field-sun">
                    <input
                        {...register("sun")}
                        type="radio"
                        name="weather"
                        value="sun"
                        id="field-sun"
                    />
                    Sunny
                </label>
                <button type="submit">
                    Send
                </button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

When I turn off `name= "weather"` and I check the buttons it does put it in the console, but it is not supposed to allow me to check all the buttons at the same time. Anyone have an idea how I can make sure I can get what is checked into the console?

Comment: If you use an `input`-field inside a `label`-element, you do not need to specify the `htmlFor` property (or the `id` property on the `input`-field for that matter).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since rain, wind, sun should be assign to the same value we need to pass same params to register function as below

```
function App() {
    const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();

    function onSubmitButton(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Order weather</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitButton)}>
                <input
                    {...register("fullName")}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Name and surname"
                    id="name"
                />
                <input
                    {...register("city")}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="City"
                    id="city"
                />
                <p>I would like to:</p>
                <label htmlFor="field-rain">
                    <input
                        {...register("weather")}
                        type="radio"
                        value="rain"
                        id="field-rain"
                    />
                    Rain
                </label>
                <label htmlFor="field-wind">
                    <input
                        {...register("weather")}
                        type="radio"
                        value="wind"
                        id="field-wind"
                    />
                    Lots of wind
                </label>
                <label htmlFor="field-sun">
                    <input
                        {...register("weather")}
                        type="radio"
                        value="sun"
                        id="field-sun"
                    />
                    Sunny
                </label>
                <button type="submit">
                    Send
                </button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I hope this will fix the issue.

Comment: Oh yes of course! What a stupid thinking error of mine. Thank you!

Comment: When using `register` I guess that you should be able to omit the `name`, right ?

Comment: @Decebal yes, `register` returns the `name` among other props.

Comment: how to make it work with checkbox? but with the same behavior, only selecting one value, not multiple as it generally is with checkboxes