# React hook form register gives error for chakra ui radio group

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

[image]

I get this error when deconstructing register inside Chakra UI Radio Group. It worked fine with select and input. How do I fix this?
I tried passing onChange={register('gender').onChange} but that didn't work either.

```
              <FormControl as="fieldset" isInvalid={!!errors.gender}>
                <RadioGroup {...register("gender")}>
                  <HStack spacing="24px">
                    <Radio value="MALE">Male</Radio>
                    <Radio value="FEMALE">Female</Radio>
                  </HStack>
                </RadioGroup>
                {errors.gender && (
                  <FormErrorMessage>{errors.gender?.message}</FormErrorMessage>
                )}
              </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This works. I got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67626877/6907703)